# Theme integration in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

I want my layout like this but left column is taking 100% width even in that folder also right column file. I am newbie so please help me.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a magento question. It is a CSS one. Nevertheless, you will need to post what css and html you are using so far.

Comment: Hi Smartie actually i want two column in my every Page. But I don't know how will be it done and what is the code and where i will put my code. please help me..........